# Difference between NULL and Empty matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, null, matrix

I have a very simple question - Difference between NULL and empty matrices in MATLAB?

NULL CASE: a = null(1) --> a is 1x0 matrix
EMPTY CASE: a = [] --> a is 0x0 matrix

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no real "null" in MATLAB, only [empty or non-empty arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-86359.html). The null you are referring to is a *function* [NULL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/null.html) which computes the orthonormal basis for the null space of a matrix. It is a linear algebra function, not a function for initializing a matrix.